# Using VS 2010 c programming to access a directory and accessing the files in it

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, file, subdirectory

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and doing a C programming. I just want to access a directory and read and perform an action on the individual files. I tried using 'dirent' but naturally that didnt work because it was not supposed to work. Next i tried using the FindFirstFile but I am having problems with the 'windows.h' header that seems to have a problem with a double assignment in baseTsd.h...! I am lost .. is there no way of doing it hassle free?

Comment: The errors from "baseTsd.h" are usually a conflict with third-party haders. Move your `#include <windows.h> to the first line of your C file and try to compile again. If that fails, get a minimum piece of code that shows the error and post it here.

Comment: @rodrigo : thanks !! the building error is gone!! so now do you think that using FinfFirstFile and FindNextFile would work if I want to access a directory and access the files in it?

Comment: #include <windows.h> is now being skipped when looking for precompiled header use..... It also doesnot recognize 'WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hFind;' and now the error says it is an undefined identifier

Comment: Yes, `FindFirstFile`/`FindNextFile` is the way to read directories in Win32. If you use precompiled headers, the best thing is to put `"#include <windows.h>"` into the PCH (probably `StdAfx.h`), at the beginning. Note that if the `#include "stdafx.h"` is not the very first line of the C file the PCH will not work.

Comment: thats exactly what i tried..

Comment: i mean thats not working..it says some elements are redefined

Comment: @rodrigo : and also, after doing all of that, the WIN32 FIND DATAFindFileData is said to be undefined identifier

Comment: Please, show us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can help you.

Comment: #include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdtypes.h"                                         

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 FILE *inputFile;
 FILE *outputFile;


 fopen_s(&inputFile,"...", "rb");
 fopen_s(&outputFile, "...", "w");
... // i want to include and reaf files from a directory here

Comment: // now in stdafx:                                                  
{
#include "targetver.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
}
// I think the "stdtypes.h" is clashing with something the windows.h needs to access , thats the reason w get the redefining error.
Even when I try to place the <windows.h> in stdafx or targetver the main doesnot compile. I also tried putting it in stdtypes.h ….. didn’t work. The error are as below:

Comment: Error 1 error C2371: 'INT32' : redefinition
Error 2 error C2371: 'UINT32' : redefinition; 
Error 3 error C2371: 'BOOLEAN' : redefinition; 

Etc etc and then I get the error that WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData; HANDLE hFind; Is undeclared.

@rodrigo

Comment: "stdtypes.h" is not a standard Win32 header, so most likely is giving conflicts. Remove it altogether or find another version that is more Windows-h-friendly. It shouldn't be hard to find.

Comment: stdtypes.h is a header that i included that contains the standard data types.. thats all